# Sort a list based on a given order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list, say `A = [[3,5],[1,3],[6,1]]`.

And I have another list, say `B = [6,1,3]`

I want to sort list `A` so that `A` becomes `[[6,1],[1,3],[3,5]]`, which fits the given `B` — i.e. the first member of each `A` sublist should be sorted according to `B`.

Comment: where is your initial code with sorting action?

Comment: what if a B item doesn't exist in A ? Also I suppose A,B are having the same length.

Comment: @coder I dont think there is any issue if the `B` doesn't exist in `A`. It's when the number from `A` doesn't exist in `B`. It kind of renders your sort meaningless as the order is defined in `B`.

Comment: @PaulRooney but since A is sorted based on B, what is the expected behavior if a B item doesn't exist in A. Do we keep this element and place it last | keep the current position ? But I'll agree with you that it is an issue also if a number form A doesn't exist in B. Generally I think that the question as is, is too broad - in a problem/algorithm there must always be some well-defined criteria.

Comment: @coder if some number doesn't exist in A, that's not an issue. Let A be some random series of letters, and let B = {'A','B','C','D','E',...}, this would mean we're sorting A alphabetically. If A doesn't contain any words starting with the letter 'x', that's not an issue.

Comment: @ErikBrodyDreyer I totally agree with you,  but in your statement you take as a condition the traditional sorting - I don't disagree with that, that's what I would do too. But in a problem its good to describe every possible behavior cause that may lead to a more efficient solution. The question as posted is not clearly stated, and that's the reason I upvoted almost all the answers.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!!

Answer (score 17):

derive a dict mapping the numbers in B to their indices and use that in the sort key function. This way you keep the key function constant time.

```
>>> A = [[3,5],[1,3],[6,1]]
>>> B = [6,1,3]
>>> srt = {b: i for i, b in enumerate(B)}
>>> sorted(A, key=lambda x: srt[x[0]])
[[6, 1], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

There are certainly a few caveats to this code. If a number were repeated in `B` you would get the index for the last entry used in the sort.

Also if there is an entry in A not matched in B, you have a `KeyError`. You could mitigate this somewhat by using `dict.get` with some default value, but if your input data was screwed to begin with, an error is a good thing to receive.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily convoluted to me. (I'd get into what I think is simpler, but I already posted an answer stating it. Just explaining my downvote.)

Comment: One dict and one sort convoluted! Well each to their own. Traditionally a downvote means that the answer is wrong (or not useful) and this is neither of those. It's usually better to have a spectrum of possible answer and this is the only answer suggesting this method.

Answer (score 11):

You can lookup where each `[0]` element of `A` is located using `.index` in `B`

```
>>> sorted(A, key = lambda i: B.index(i[0]))
[[6, 1], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

or in-place sort

```
>>> A.sort(key = lambda i: B.index(i[0]))
>>> A
[[6, 1], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: `list.index` really isn't very efficient here...

Comment: This is a good answer if you like slow and inefficient code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are free to suggest an alternative :) This is what came to my mind in the 6 minutes between reading the question and when I wrote my answer. If speed is that big of a deal there are optimizations to be made

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `A` and `B` have the same length, each of the first elements of the tuples in `A` corresponds to an element in `B` and there are no duplicates, you can use this:

```
>>> A = [[3,5],[1,3],[6,1]]
>>> B = [6,1,3]
>>> A_ind = {b: [b, a] for (b, a) in A}
>>> [A_ind[b] for b in B]
[[6, 1], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

This simply creates a `dict`, mapping the `b` part from `A` to the whole elements and looking up the respective elements in `B` in that `dict`. Using neither `sorted` not `index`, this has complexity of O(n).

If there *can* be duplicate elements, you can create a `dict` (or `defaultdict`) mapping keys to lists of elements having that key:

```
>>> A = [[3,5],[1,3],[6,1],[1,4]]
>>> A_ind = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for b, a in A:
...     A_ind[b].append([b,a])
...     
>>> B = [6,1,3,1]
>>> [a for b in B for a in A_ind[b]]
[[6, 1], [1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

Or turn the `list` into `iter`ators to distribute the values in `A` to the matching keys in `B`:

```
>>> A_ind = {k: iter(v) for k, v in A_ind.items()}
>>> [next(A_ind[b]) for b in B]
[[6, 1], [1, 3], [3, 5], [1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to CoryKramer's answer but it is a bit faster. Instead of using the sort function, manually insert items to a another list. This way the `index` method gets called less often. (This code assumes the elements in b are distinct).

```
a= [[3,5],[1,3],[6,1]]
b=[6,1,3]

c= [-1]*len(b) # dummy data

for x in a:
    c[b.index(x[0])]= x

print(c)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if `a= [[3,5],[1,3],[6,1],[1,7]]` and `b=[6,1,3,1]`

Comment: @coder OP didn't specify anything like that so I assumed the elements in list b will be distinct.

Comment: you better mention that assumption to your answer then.

Comment: The OP's problem is ill-defined if there are duplicates

Comment: This doesn't actually call `index` any less often, because `sorted` saves the key function results.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(A, key=lambda x: B.index(x[0]))
```

Comment: Identical duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365677/4909087