# Sort a list of strings using a user-provided order in Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a list of strings, say `['ayyaaauu', 'shhasyhh', 'shaash']` and an accompanying order list `['s', 'y', 'u', 'h', 'a']`.

I want to sort the list of strings using the order list in place of the normal alphabetical order used in sorting.

`sorted(['ayyaaauu', 'shhasyhh', 'shaash'])` would return `['ayyaaauu', 'shaash', 'shhasyhh']`, sorting using alphabetical order.

I want the sort function to return `['shhasyhh', 'shaash', 'ayyaaauu']`, which is the alphabet order specified in the order list.

Similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365565/sort-a-list-based-on-a-given-order) are only useful if you only consider the first element of the string. I want to sequentially consider the entire string if the previous letters are the same.

P.S. In practice, I am generating the list of strings using letters from the order list, so all the letters in the strings have a "correct" order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sorted()`, and then generate the `key` parameter by using `map()` to map each letter to its priority (`sorted()` then uses tuple comparison to generate the ordering):

```py
data = ['ayyaaauu', 'shhasyhh', 'shaash']
ordering = ['s', 'y', 'u', 'h', 'a']
priorities = {letter: index for index, letter in enumerate(ordering)}

result = sorted(data, key=lambda x: tuple(map(lambda y: priorities[y], x)))

# Prints ['shhasyhh', 'shaash', 'ayyaaauu']
print(result)
```