# How can I arrange the output in ascending order given a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to generate 13 objects in random the output must in ascending order or from highest in ranking, it is as follows

Order of suits from lowest to highest is Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades
order of values from lowest to highest is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A

My code prints 13 random cards but there is no order. How can I sort it according to the ranking above?

This is my code:

```
import itertools
import random

value = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
suits = ['C','D','H','S']

deck = list(itertools.product(vals, suits))

random.shuffle(deck)

for val, suit in deck:
    print('%s-%s' % (val, suit))
```

The output should look like this:

```
A-C,2-C,3-C,4-C,5-C,6-C,7-C,8-C,9-C,10-C,J-C,Q-C,K-C
```

Comment: The output does NOT look like that.  Are you saying that's what you want?  You need to add `end=','` to the `print` statement.

Comment: @TimRoberts yep no I worded that part wrong that it what it SHOULD look like  my code prints it vertically. I edited my question

Comment: @TimRoberts like this? print('%s-%s' % (val, suit) end=',')

Comment: „ How can I sort it also make it print horizontally and separated with a comma.“ These are several separate tasks, and as far as I remember at least two of them should be covered on [so] with very similar wording. Which *one* of these are you struggling with or at least would focus on first?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oh okay maybe I should focus first on arranging it. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method uses a helper function as key for the card sorting.  A deck is constructed, shuffled and 13 cards are taken.  Then the hand is sorted.  Ace is low in this case.

```
import random, itertools

values = ['A', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
suits = ['C','D','H','S']

def card_value(card):
    val, suit = card.split('-')
    return suits.index(suit) + 10*values.index(val)

deck = [f'{v}-{s}' for v,s in itertools.product(values, suits)]
random.shuffle(deck)
hand = deck[:13]

print(sorted(hand, key=card_value, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Printing

You can take advantage of the `sep` argument to `print`. We'll flatten a generator expression to create string representations of each card, and specify these separate items printed should be separated by `','` with `'\n'` being printed at the end.

```
print(*(f"{c}-{s}" for c, s in deck), sep=',', end='\n')
```

Output:

```
2-S,A-S,3-C,9-D,A-D,9-C,5-C,3-H,A-C,5-H,3-D,4-S,K-D,2-H,Q-C,5-S,J-S,6-D,2-C,4-C,4-H,8-S,3-S,J-D,A-H,J-C,6-C,8-D,9-H,4-D,10-H,9-S,6-S,7-H,7-D,K-C,10-D,8-H,2-D,8-C,Q-S,K-H,7-C,5-D,J-H,10-S,K-S,7-S,Q-D,6-H,Q-H,10-C
```

### Ordering

For order, I'm not sure why you are shuffling if you want the cards in order.

Given the order you want, you should reorder your lists *slightly*, and then use a list comprehension to generate the card combos.

```
value = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']

deck = [(c, s) for c in value for s in suits]
# [('2', 'C'), ('2', 'D'), ('2', 'H'), ('2', 'S'), ('3', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('4', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('4', 'S'), ('5', 'C'), ('5', 'D'), ('5', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('6', 'C'), ('6', 'D'), ('6', 'H'), ('6', 'S'), ('7', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('7', 'H'), ('7', 'S'), ('8', 'C'), ('8', 'D'), ('8', 'H'), ('8', 'S'), ('9', 'C'), ('9', 'D'), ('9', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('10', 'C'), ('10', 'D'), ('10', 'H'), ('10', 'S'), ('J', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('J', 'H'), ('J', 'S'), ('Q', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'S'), ('K', 'C'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'H'), ('K', 'S'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'S')]
```

Now the same print as before yields:

```
2-C,2-D,2-H,2-S,3-C,3-D,3-H,3-S,4-C,4-D,4-H,4-S,5-C,5-D,5-H,5-S,6-C,6-D,6-H,6-S,7-C,7-D,7-H,7-S,8-C,8-D,8-H,8-S,9-C,9-D,9-H,9-S,10-C,10-D,10-H,10-S,J-C,J-D,J-H,J-S,Q-C,Q-D,Q-H,Q-S,K-C,K-D,K-H,K-S,A-C,A-D,A-H,A-S
```

### Sorting

If you want to shuffle the deck, take 13 cards at random, then sort those, you can use `sorted` with a lambda function that generates a tuple of the position of the value and the suit in the original lists.

```
random.shuffle(deck)

top13 = deck[:13]
top13_sorted = sorted(top13, key=lambda card: (value.index(card[0]), suits.index(card[1])))
```

For a run here, `top13_sorted` is now:

```
[('2', 'S'), ('3', 'D'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('4', 'S'), ('7', 'D'), ('7', 'H'), ('8', 'H'), ('9', 'C'), ('10', 'C'), ('J', 'C'), ('J', 'H'), ('K', 'H')]
```

Comment: So it has to be random but show those random cards in order. How do I limit the print to only show the first 13 cards?

Comment: In the print, replace `deck` with a slice of `deck`? `deck[:13]`

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer, but hope it can solve your problem

```
import itertools
import random

def sortedValue(card_list):
    return sorted(card_list, key = lambda s: s[0])

def sortedSuit(card_list):
    return sorted(card_list, key = lambda s: s[1])

def chooseCards(deck):
    card = 0
    card_list = []
    for val, suit in deck:
        card_list.append((val_level_dict.get(val), suit_level_dict.get(suit)))
        # print('%s-%s' % (val, suit))
        card += 1
        if card == 13:
            break
        
    return card_list

val = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
suit = ['C','D','H','S']

val_level_dict = {
    '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4, '6': 5, '7': 6, '8': 7, '9': 8, '10': 9, 'J': 10, 'Q': 11, 'K': 12, 'A': 13
}

suit_level_dict = {
    'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'H': 3, 'S': 4
}

val_map = {v: k for k, v in val_level_dict.items()}
suit_map = {v: k for k, v in suit_level_dict.items()}

deck = list(itertools.product(val, suit))

random.shuffle(deck)

card_list = chooseCards(deck)
sorted_cards = sortedValue(sortedSuit(card_list))
mapped_cards = [val_map.get(val) + '-' + suit_map.get(suit) for val, suit in sorted_cards]

for card in mapped_cards:
    print(card, end=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to [Sort a list based on a given order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365565/sort-a-list-based-on-a-given-order)

You should first create the list of order of how the card deck should be, which is as 2-C, 2-D, .... A-S

To do so,

```
value = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
suits = ['C','D','H','S']
#generate the key
srt = {f"{a}-{b}": x*4 + y for x,a in enumerate(value) for y,b in enumerate(suits)}
```

Based on the key above, you can now sort your deck.
Your deck should be

```
deck = list(itertools.product(value, suits))
random.shuffle(deck)
#change the deck from list to string
deck = [f'{y[0]}-{y[1]}' for y in deck[:13]]
sorted(deck, key=lambda x: srt[x])
```

the result should be now in ascending order as you wish. (Refer to below for result)

```
['2-C', '2-H', '3-H', '4-D', '5-C', '5-H', '6-C', '6-D', '6-H', '7-C', '8-D', '9-C', 'K-S']
```

** Edited, add on Result
** Edited, add on to get 13 card only

Comment: I only need it to print 13 cards your code printed out way more. Can I ask how to make it print only 13?

Comment: Maybe you can consider taking the first 13 from the deck? Change the deck code to as such:-
deck = [f'{y[0]}-{y[1]}' for y in deck[:13]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which list has sorting priority, and your example doesn't really help since all the cards have the same suit.

If you want them sorted by value first and then by suit you can use:

#### sorting by value then by suit

```
random.shuffle(deck)

sorted_deck = sorted(deck, key=lambda x: (value.index(x[0]) * (len(value) + 1)) + suits.index(x[1]))
```

or if you want them sorted by suit first you could use

#### Sorting by suit then by value

```
random.shuffle(deck)

sorted_deck = sorted(deck, key=lambda x: value.index(x[0]) + (suits.index(x[1]) * (len(suits) + 1)))
```

If you only want 13 cards then all you need to do is slice your unsorted list before feeding it to the sorting algorithm:

```
random.shuffle(deck)
deck = deck[:13]
# then use the sorting algorithms above
```

Then to print them all on one line you could do:

```
print(','.join(['-'.join(i) for i in sorted_deck]))
```

output:

```
# sorting by suit then by value
A-C,2-C,3-C,4-C,5-C,6-C,7-C,8-C,9-C,10-C,J-C,Q-C,K-C,A-D,2-D,3-D,4-D,5-D,6-D,7-D,8-D,9-D,10-D,J-D,Q-D,K-D,A-H,2-H,3-H,4-H,5-H,6-H,7-H,8-H,9-H,10-H,J-H,Q-H,K-H,A-S,2-S,3-S,4-S,5-S,6-S,7-S,8-S,9-S,1
0-S,J-S,Q-S,K-S


# sorting by value then by suit
A-C,A-D,A-H,A-S,2-C,2-D,2-H,2-S,3-C,3-D,3-H,3-S,4-C,4-D,4-H,4-S,5-C,5-D,5-H,5-S,6-C,6-D,6-H,6-S,7-C,7-D,7-H,7-S,8-C,8-D,8-H,8-S,9-C,9-D,9-H,9-S,10-C,10-D,10-H,10-S,J-C,J-D,J-H,J-S,Q-C,Q-D,Q-H,Q-S,
K-C,K-D,K-H,K-S
```

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, sorting is easier than you've shown. Simply create a tuple in the appropriate order. Whichever value goes first will have higher precedence for sorting. No math required.

Comment: My way is more efficient, I think i will stick with it.