# How to remove the last comma when printing a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code

```
houses = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
ranks = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
deck = []

for house in houses:
    for rank in ranks:
        deck.append(f"{rank}-{house}")

for i in range(13):
    print(deck[i], end=",")`
```

The output is supposed to be:

```
A-C,2-C,3-C,4-C,5-C,6-C,7-C,8-C,9-C,10-C,J-C,Q-C,K-C
```

but I got

```
A-C,2-C,3-C,4-C,5-C,6-C,7-C,8-C,9-C,10-C,J-C,Q-C,K-C,
```

How do I remove the last comma?

Comment: Maybe just print(','.join(deck[:13]))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you make a comma-separated string from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative

```
houses = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
ranks = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
deck = []

for house in houses:
    for rank in ranks:
        deck.append(f"{rank}-{house}")

print(*deck[:13], sep=',')
```

Comment: If your next question is about sorting the cards then [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74231455/how-can-i-arrange-the-output-in-ascending-order-given-a-list/74231948#74231948)

Answer (score 0):

Might suggest combining `str.join` and `itertools.product` as below:

```
from itertools import product


decks = [
    ','.join(
        '-'.join((rank, house)) for (house, rank) in product(house, ranks)
    )
    for house in houses
]
for deck in decks:
    print(deck)
```

Output:

```
A-C,2-C,3-C,4-C,5-C,6-C,7-C,8-C,9-C,10-C,J-C,Q-C,K-C
A-D,2-D,3-D,4-D,5-D,6-D,7-D,8-D,9-D,10-D,J-D,Q-D,K-D
A-H,2-H,3-H,4-H,5-H,6-H,7-H,8-H,9-H,10-H,J-H,Q-H,K-H
A-S,2-S,3-S,4-S,5-S,6-S,7-S,8-S,9-S,10-S,J-S,Q-S,K-S
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is the last part of your code, where you are looping over the deck & printing it.

First of all, it's the best to use `len(deck)` instead of a constant number.

Lastly just subtract 1 from the amount you are looping & print the last one separately.

So your fixed code would be.

```py
for i in range(len(deck)-1):
  print(deck[i], end=",")

print(deck[-1])
```